# Xamarin.Forms - CollectionView doesn't show size of Images correctly with label

Tags: xamarin.forms, uicollectionview

I have a collection view that shows book covers and their title. The problem is that once I put the label under the image tag, the image resizes itself not corresponding to 200x145 like I set in the code.

Here's the code:

```xml
<CollectionView HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
                Margin="0,0,20,15" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding AuthorBooks}"
                VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                ItemsLayout="HorizontalList"
                HeightRequest="210">
     <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <Grid Margin="8,0">
                 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                     <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                     <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                 </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                 <PanCake:PancakeView Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,20,0">
                     <ffimageloading:CachedImage Source="{Binding Cover,TargetNullValue='noimage_placeholder'}" HeightRequest="200" WidthRequest="145">
                         <ffimageloading:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
                             <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding GoToBookDetailPage, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodels:BookPageViewModel}}}"
                                                   CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                         </ffimageloading:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
                     </ffimageloading:CachedImage>
                 </PanCake:PancakeView>
                 <Label Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="14" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="Start" FontFamily="Inter" WidthRequest="145" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" MaxLines="2" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Black"/>
             </Grid>
         </DataTemplate>
     </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

This is how it looks like:
[image: This is how it looks like]

The image should cover up all the space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the `*` for both of the Grid's RowDefinitions. When you use the `*` for both it means that they both will receive 50% of the available space.

Change the second RowDefinition either to `auto`:

```xml
<Grid Margin="8,0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <PanCake:PancakeView Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,20,0">
        <ffimageloading:CachedImage Source="{Binding Cover,TargetNullValue='noimage_placeholder'}" HeightRequest="200" WidthRequest="145">
            <ffimageloading:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding GoToBookDetailPage, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodels:BookPageViewModel}}}"
                                      CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
            </ffimageloading:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
        </ffimageloading:CachedImage>
    </PanCake:PancakeView>
    <Label Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="14" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="Start" FontFamily="Inter" WidthRequest="145" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" MaxLines="2" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Black"/>
</Grid>
```

or to a fixed value such as `40`:

```xml
<Grid Margin="8,0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <PanCake:PancakeView Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,20,0">
        <ffimageloading:CachedImage Source="{Binding Cover,TargetNullValue='noimage_placeholder'}" HeightRequest="200" WidthRequest="145">
            <ffimageloading:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding GoToBookDetailPage, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodels:BookPageViewModel}}}"
                                      CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
            </ffimageloading:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
        </ffimageloading:CachedImage>
    </PanCake:PancakeView>
    <Label Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="14" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="Start" FontFamily="Inter" WidthRequest="145" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" MaxLines="2" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Black"/>
</Grid>
```

Alternatively, you can also use factors with the `*`, e.g. in order to give the image 3/4 of the available space and the rest to the label, you would do:

```xml
<Grid Margin="8,0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <PanCake:PancakeView Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,20,0">
        <ffimageloading:CachedImage Source="{Binding Cover,TargetNullValue='noimage_placeholder'}" HeightRequest="200" WidthRequest="145">
            <ffimageloading:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding GoToBookDetailPage, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodels:BookPageViewModel}}}"
                                      CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
            </ffimageloading:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
        </ffimageloading:CachedImage>
    </PanCake:PancakeView>
    <Label Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="14" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="Start" FontFamily="Inter" WidthRequest="145" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" MaxLines="2" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Black"/>
</Grid>
```